# Code not running synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I am writing a script for a clothing website that chooses your correct size, adds it to the cart and redirects you to the checkout page.

`var size = "Medium";
$("#size option:contains(" + size + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
$("input[name='commit']").click();
window.location.replace("checkout link here");`

That is the code that I have written so far. It seems that it redirects before it has the chance to add the article to the cart. I have tried `window.setTimeout` without success. How would I set it so it can add the article to the cart *before* it redirect? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course it wont work.. when you click the submit button if this is a form then it has to go to the server to accomplish the transaction.. then you can redirect the client to the checkout from SERVER not from CLIENT..

Comment: Otherwise you can do that using AJAX to asynchronously add to the cart then redirect to the cart upon AJAX success.

Comment: What @MohammedR.El-Khoudary said... look at setting the [`Location` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) from your server side script.

Comment: @MohammedR.El-Khoudary The website uses a standardized checkout page (/checkout)

Comment: Please review my answer below.. I wrote you a solution if you can't modify the checkout page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try submitting the request through AJAX then do the redirect.. it will be done this way:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "Your Cart Addition Link",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: {}//Your Cart Addition Parameters
      }).done(function(data) {
        window.location.replace("checkout link here");
      });
```

This way things will go OK.. or just go with server side redirection if you can control server pages.

Comment: I am fairly new to JavaScript, what would I put in the url section where you wrote "Your Cart Addition Link", it is not a link that adds it to the cart, it is a jquery command

Comment: Can you post the jQuery command here? if it is an asynchronous AJAX call then all we have to do is to hook your callback with its done state.

Comment: $("input[name='commit']").click();

Comment: This isn't enough.. it might be calling a form submit or calling an AJAX event.. Please tell me if you just left the .click() without the redirect does the page leaves to another one?

Comment: It stays on the same page when you execute $("input[name='commit']").click();

Comment: It certainly uses AJAX to do the job.. well we can get notified about completion by using a Mutation Observer but that's kind of a hack.. Site developers can help you by giving you the right callback to hook to..

Answer (score 0):

Just use AJAX and then use a callback function to redirect the user (or do whatever you want)
You wrote a sync code and of course it will not work properly.